# Grouping levels into larger groups in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, multi-level

I'm attempting to put all the levels of a factor into a few groups (and other levels) that I've created separately. I used the following code to remove missing values and unnecessary levels from each variable defined as a factor. "gss" is the original dataset, and "wrkslf" and "income06" are the variables that I'm going to use.

```
v1 <- select(gss, wrkslf, income06) %>% na.omit() %>% filter(income06 != "Refused")
```

The problem of "income06" is that there's too many levels on it. It looks like this:

```
income06        count
Under $1 000    103     
$1 000 To 2 999 95      
$3 000 To 3 999 78      
$4 000 To 4 999 48      
$5 000 To 5 999 78      
$6 000 To 6 999 91      
$7 000 To 7 999 114     
$8 000 To 9 999 179     
$10000 To 12499 345     
$12500 To 14999 291
...
```

So I tried to run the following code to put the levels into larger groups that I made:

```
v2 = v1 %>% group_by(income06) %>% summarise(count = n())

v2 <- v2 %>%  mutate(tidyIncomeLevel = recode(income06,
"UNDER $1 000" = "Under $1,000",
"$1 000 TO 2 999" = "Under $10,000",
"$3 000 TO 3 999" = "Under $10,000",
"$4 000 TO 4 999" = "Under $10,000",
"$5 000 TO 5 999" = "Under $10,000",
"$6 000 TO 6 999" = "Under $10,000",
"$7 000 TO 7 999" = "Under $10,000",
"$8 000 TO 8 999" = "Under $10,000",
"$9 000 TO 9 999" = "Under $10,000",
"$10000 TO 12499" = "Under $25,000",
"$12500 TO 14999" = "Under $25,000",
"$15000 TO 17499" = "Under $25,000",
"$17500 TO 19999" = "Under $25,000",
"$20000 TO 22499" = "Under $25,000",
"$22500 TO 24999" = "Under $25,000",
"$25000 TO 29999" = "Under $40,000",
"$30000 TO 34999" = "Under $40,000",
"$35000 TO 39999" = "Under $40,000",
"$40000 TO 49999" = "Under $60,000",
"$50000 TO 59999" = "Under $60,000",
"$60000 TO 74999" = "Under $90,000",
"$75000 TO 89999" = "Under $90,000",
"$90000 TO 109999" = "Under $150,000",
"$110000 TO 129999" = "Under $150,000",
"$130000 TO 149999" = "Under $150,000"))
```

Of course, I installed every packages that I need to use the functions above, but in v2, the function I wrote didn't work at all. How can I fix the code so that I can use the integrated groups as new levels?
Do you have better idea to see the output more simple and concise?

Answer (score 0):

The forcats package has respective convenience functions:

```
x <- c("A1", "A2", "B2", "B1", "A3") 
library(forcats)
xCondense <- fct_collapse(x, A = c("A1", "A2", "A3"), B = c("B1", "B2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The *forcats* package has great tools for working with factors.

```
library(forcats)
gss <- data.frame(income0 = sample(1:9, size = 100, replace = TRUE) * 1000) %>% 
    mutate(income06 = fct_reorder(.f = factor(paste0("$", income0, " TO ", income0 + 999)), .x = income0))
summarise(group_by(gss, income06), count = n())
# # A tibble: 9 x 2
# income06      count
# <fct>         <int>
# 1 $1000 TO 1999     5
# 2 $2000 TO 2999    11
# 3 $3000 TO 3999    14
# ...

gss <- gss %>%  mutate(tidyIncomeLevel = fct_recode(income06,
    "Under $5,000" = "UNDER $1 000",
    "Under $5,000" = "$1000 TO 1999",
    "Under $5,000" = "$2000 TO 2999",
    "Under $5,000" = "$3000 TO 3999",
    "Under $5,000" = "$4000 TO 4999",
    "Under $10,000" = "$5000 TO 5999",
    "Under $10,000" = "$6000 TO 6999",
    "Under $10,000" = "$7000 TO 7999",
    "Under $10,000" = "$8000 TO 8999",
    "Under $10,000" = "$9000 TO 9999",
    "Under $25,000" = "$10000 TO 12499"))

summarise(group_by(gss, tidyIncomeLevel), count = n())
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# tidyIncomeLevel count
# <fct>           <int>
# 1 Under $5,000       39
# 2 Under $10,000      61
```